# Sequence,Limit,Convergence

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have found out the formula of a_n by recursion method but after that I am being unable to show that it converges.

Comment: What is the formula you obtained ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** let $b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and write an equation for $b_n$; then show it converges.

Comment: I have got the equation,but its very complicated so having trouble to show convergence.

Comment: Which equation that you got?

Answer (score 0):

If $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$ are the roots of $x^2-3x-1=0$, then 
$$
a_n=c_1\kappa_1^n+c_2\kappa_2^n.
$$
We have that $\kappa_{1,2}=\dfrac{3}{2}\pm\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$,and also that $c_1,c_2\ne 0$, as $a_n$ takes integral values.

Hence
$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{c_1\kappa_1^{n+1}+c_2\kappa_2^{n+1}}{c_1\kappa_1^n+c_2\kappa_2^n}\to\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{2}.
$$

Comment: It was really a simple calculation from there,shame on me.
Anyway thanks a lott.

Answer (score 0):

As Yiorgos S. Smyrlis answered, you probably found that $$a_n=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{1
   3}}{2}\right)^n}{\sqrt{13}}$$ So, $$b_n=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}-\left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^{n+1}}{\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n-\left(\frac
   {3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)^n}=\frac{\alpha ^{n+1}-\beta ^{n+1}}{\alpha ^n-\beta ^n}$$  with $\alpha >1,\beta <1$. When $n$ becomes large, $\beta^n$ becomes smaller and smaller while $\alpha^n$ becomes larger and larger. So, basically, for large values of $n$ $$b_n\approx \frac{\alpha ^{n+1}}{\alpha ^n}=\alpha=\dfrac{3}{2}+\dfrac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$$

Comment: It was really a simple calculation from there,shame on me.
Anyway thanks a lott.

Comment: You are welcome ! No shame on you and I am glad to have been of some help.